# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent Component which updates a every second its array `myValue`. In a child component I want to create a chart which uses this array as data and updates also every time the parent updates.

When I run this application I get this error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'hidden: true'. Current
>   value: 'hidden: false'.

Here is my parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {

    private myValues: MyValue[];
    private alive: boolean;

    constructor(private valueService: ValueService) {
    this.alive = true;
    this.myValues = [];
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    TimerObservable.create(0, 1000)
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.valueService.doSmth().subscribe(
          value => {
            this.myValues.push(value);
          }
        );
      });
  }
...

}
```

The parent template looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let value of myValues">
    <p>{{value.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<app-value-chart [chartData] = myValues></app-value-chart>
```

And here is my child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-value-chart',
  templateUrl: './value-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./value-chart.component.scss']
)}
export class ValueChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() chartData: MyValue[];

  chart: any;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.createChart(); // creates chart with ChartJS
    const tmp: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.chartData.length; i++) {
      tmp.push(this.chartData[i].x);
    }
    this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = tmp;
    this.chart.update(0);
  }
...
}
```

Child template:

```
  <canvas id="canvas" responsive>{{ chart }}</canvas>
```

How can I solve my problem?

I use Angular 6.

Comment: Explicitly call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges after modifying the data, or you could wrap the update inside a setTimeout

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find detailed explanations about that exception in [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error). One technique to eliminate the exception is to force change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`:

```
export class ValueChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        ...
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    ...
}
```

An alternative technique is to run the handler code asynchronously with `setTimeout`:

```
export class ValueChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            ...
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!!

Comment: The linked article has moved to here: [link](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error)