# How to change template in Parent based on child route data in Angular

Tags: angular

So, imagine in a Angular 4 application there is a Parent component which has a router-outlet for child component.

Now how can we change something in Parent component (for example container around child component) based on route data of the child component ?

Tried setting via a service but get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973502/1009922) may help you.

Comment: Thanks, tried that already and routing just stopped working.