# Pass a variable between 2 children components produces ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 children components that must be passed information.

parent.component.html

```
<childA [loading]="loading">
    <childB (loadingChanged)="loadingChangedHandler($event)"></childB>
</childA>
```

parent.component.ts

```
loading = false;
constructor(){
   ......
}
loadingChangedHandler(loadingChild: boolean){
    this.loading = loadingChild;
  }
```

childB.component.ts (pass a variable to parent, and this value go to child A)

```
....
@Output() loadingChanged: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
....
loadData() {
    this.loadingChanged.emit(true);
      this.service.readDate()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            ........
            this.loadingChanged.emit(false);
        })

  }
```

And finally in the childA component  I must receive the variable and perform operations

childA.component.ts

```
@Input() loading: boolean = false
constructor() {
....}
....
```

In child A I have a loading spinner that works, but I get an error in the console that says:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'loading: false'.
>   Current value: 'loading: true'.

How do I solve the problem?
There is documentation about it (ngAfterViewInit) but I can not understand why it does not work in my case.

Comment: look at this i think similer type  problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072065/after-child-has-been-initialised-operation-from-parent-component-on-child-dom-c/54072543#54072543

Comment: This problem have @ViewChild directive, I dont use that, my code only one value passes between child components

Answer (score 0):

Angular runs change detection and when its find that some values which have been passed to the child component have been changed Angular throws the error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError [*Read here in detail*](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

To solve your problem, you can use the AfterContentChecked life cycle hook in  ***childA.component.ts***

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
  private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {

    this.cdref.detectChanges();

  }
```

Comment: I additional add export class ChildA implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked ..., but still doesnt work. In this moment, I only recive the value of @Input() loading in ChildA, but I dont do anything with it and the error persists

Comment: If it works, in the console the error is marked in the line <childA [loading] = "loading">

Answer (score 0):

> Imp: Angular, in development mode runs the change detection twice.

Since in the first change detection phase, it identified that the parent component's loading property was changed and in the next change detection cycle it observed that the loading property was changed again by the child component and hence it threw an exception because the loading property was changed after all the it was checked by the first cycle  .

In production mode you won't get this error as in prod mode change detection runs only once.  This is why it is important to turn the development mode on so that we know these types of errors in advance which can cause inconsistency between data and view.

Putting  the code that modifies the loading property in setTimeout ensures that the code is run in next tick when the previous change detection was completed.

Try putting this.loadingChanged.emit(false); in setTimeout with 0.

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.loadingChanged.emit(false);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Your solution works but put                                                                           
setTimeout(() => { this.loadingSubfamiliesChanged.emit(true); }, 0); this.service.rea...                                                And without changing the code in ChildA component, Can You explain for what reason this works?

Comment: I am updating the answer why you need setTimeout there.

Comment: Can you explain for what reason the solution with ngAfterContentChecked() or  ngAfterViewInit() in the ChildA component doesnt work? I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973032/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-in-child-component)  but I dont understand for what reason the setTimeout works similar to  ngAfterViewInit() @Ritesh